# How to testing nested custom reactive component in Angular with jasmine-karma

Tags: angular, testing, nested, karma-jasmine

I have a question please,

I have a parent and a child components.

Here is the

.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
 parentForm: FormGroup;

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

 private createForm(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
  firstName: [undefined, []],
  lastName: [undefined, []]
  });
 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.parentForm = this.createForm();
 }

}
```

.html

```
<form [formGroup]="parentForm">
 ...
 <app-nested [parentForm]="parentForm"></app-nested>
</form>
```

The nested form:

.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nested',
  templateUrl: './nested.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nested.component.scss']
})
export class NestedComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() parentForm: FormGroup;
 nestedForm: FormGroup;

 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

 private createForm(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
  email: [undefined, [Validators.email]],
  phone: [undefined, []]
  });
 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.nestedForm = this.createForm();
  this.parentForm.addControl('details', this.nestedForm);
  this.nestedForm.setParent(this.parentForm);
 }

}
```

.html

```
<form [formGroup]="nestedForm">
 ...
</form>
```

My question is, how to "include" in the nestedForm in the spec.ts file into the nestedForm? So how can I "notify" the parentForm there is a child form in it?

I began to try something similar:

At first I declare it in the describe

```
  let component: ParentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ParentComponent>;
  let componentNested: NestedComponent;
  let fixtureNested: ComponentFixture<NestedComponent>;
```

in the before each I configure a TestBed and in it

```
    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [NestedComponent],
          imports: [
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
          ]
        }).detectChanges();
    
    
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [ParentComponent],
          imports: [
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
          ]
        }).detectChanges();
    });


  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixtureNested = TestBed.createComponent(NestedComponent);
    componentNested = fixture.componentInstance;
    componentNested.parentForm = component;
  }
```